# Requiring js file containing 'ref' and 'ffi' node modules from react file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am trying to implement react with electron. I have used custom library in my electron app, for which I had to use 'ffi' and 'ref' module. Now when i try to require the js file which has 'ffi' and 'ref' module in it from react,I get binding error. Whereas if I require any other js file of electron app from react, it works perfect.
Also initially when using 'ffi' and 'ref', I was getting the same error, but after rebuilding these modules as per electron (electron-rebuild -f -w ref & electron=rebuild -f  -w ffi), it started working fine.

Comment: Would need more info on your setup. I'm using TypeScript and SystemJS. I import plain JS libraries and 'require' node ones like ffi and ref and everything just works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack to bundle your react files you should add a field : `target: 'electron'`, to the exported object in webpack.config.js

Comment: If you get this error when you try to view the application in the browser it's normal, because you have to test it via electron!

Comment: Of course m not trying in browser. I am trying via electron. Nwz, not using react anymore. The code generated from typescript is giving error. So going with normal JS and JQuery